# Qt- How to display the Text Edit String in a List View?

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qlistview, qt4.8, qpushbutton

I have a ***QTextEdit , 2 QPushButtons*** (Add n Remove Buttons) and a ***QListView***. When i am entering the text in the Text Edit and ***click the  Add Button, the Text should be added in the List View.*** Then, if I select any one of the ***added text from the List View & Click the Remove Button, the Text should be removed from the ListView.*** I dont know how to achieve this. Plz Help me to solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What model are you using for the QListView? QStandardItemModel, or your own model?

Comment: i'm using QStandardItemModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstandarditemmodel.html) and you have the following variables

```
QPushButton* addButton;
QPushButton* removeButton;
QTextEdit* textEdit;
QStandardItemModel* model;
MyObject* this;
```

the following code should do it:

```
connect(addButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onAddButtonClicked()));
connect(removeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onRemoveButtonClicked()));
```

Then the two slots in your class MyObject you define do the following:

```
void MyObject::onAddButtonClicked() {
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(textEdit->plainText());
}

void MyObject::onRemoveButtonClicked() {
    if (model->rowCount() == 0)
        return;
    delete model->takeItem(model->rowCount() - 1);
}
```

Updating the view gets handled by `QStandardItemModel`

Comment: Hi.. Now i want to scroll this list widget items in a widget. How can i do that? plz help..

Comment: I guess simply putting it into a [QScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) should do (using `setWidget()`). Not sure if I understand the question correctly though.

Comment: Hi.. If i use this                                                  void MyObject::onAddButtonClicked() {
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItemModel(textEdit->plainText());
} it throws me an error:'QStandardItemModel::QStandardItemModel(QObject *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QString' to 'QObject *'
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called. How can i solve this.

Comment: Oops seems this is a typo in my answer. It should be `QStandardItem` instead

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know how to use model/view/controller pattern, I'd recommend you to use QListWidget instead of QListView.
Adding to QListWidget is way to simplier. You should create a slot where goes the signal from **add button** click, and a slot for **delete button** click.

Code for first slot:

```
m_pListWidget->addItem( m_pTextEdit->toPlainText() );
```

Code for second slot:

```
if ( QListWidgetItem* plwiCurrent = m_pListWidget->currentItem() )
{
    m_pListWidget->takeItem( m_pListWidget->row( plwiCurrent ) );
    delete plwiCurrent;
}
```

Comment: Hi.. The code for Second Slot throws me an error: 'QListWidget::takeItem': Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QListWidgetItem *' to 'int'. why this is happening?

Comment: Okay, my bad, changing the answer. Use `m_pListWidget->takeItem( m_pListWidget->row( plwiCurrent ) );` instead.

Comment: Hi.. Now i want to scroll this list widget items in a widget. How can i do this? plz help...

Comment: I guess I don't understand you. What do you mean by `scroll this list widget items in a widget`?

Comment: when i'm clicking the addbutton the text in QTextEdit will be added in the QListView. i had did this using QStandardItemModel. Now I want this items to Scroll in a separate widget. eg. Hello World is my item in the QListView. This Hello World has to scroll from right to left in a separate Widget like a Ticker.